# Why does Stylish user CSS override author CSS?

Tags: css

Example page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background: black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Example user CSS in any user CSS browser addon (e.g. stylish or stylus):

```
body {
    background: white;
}
```

If I remember cascading rules correct, I should see a black page because author CSS beats user CSS by importance if none of them have !important thingy. However, my browser shows me a white page. Why does it happen?

Comment: maybe they added it later, check this using dev tools

Comment: What browser and extension format are you using?

Comment: @zero298, firefox 59.0 and whatever they enforce since quantum... webext i guess?

Comment: the extensions use either `!important` or wait for the document to load.

Comment: @TemaniAfif wait, should it actually matter since rules have different origin (user and author)?
well, anyway, white rule is higher than black rule and black rule is crossed out, but both of them are present

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa that's weird, so importance cascading doesn't matter anymore? because i certainly remember that there was a time when my stylesheet worked properly in such cases. 
is there any legit way to fix that or should i go to the stylish bugtracker?

Comment: Are you the one making the add-in ? or what are you trying to do ?

Comment: i'm trying to make user css stylesheet that fixes incorrect UA theming (dark GTK themes somehow affect pages with no specified background, rendering them unreadable), i'm just using the addin to set that stylesheet globally but without affecting pages that already have background styles. i'm not the author of either of those extensions.

Answer (score 0):

> However, my browser shows me a white page. Why does it happen?

have you tried hard refresh? `ctrl + shift + r`
something might be stored in your cache. as you can see in the snippet below, everything works as expected

```css
body {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background: black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```